# Alter Time of DateTime Field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I am needing to alter the time piece of a datetime field.  I tried to use this syntax, but it gives me an error of

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword as

What syntax can I use to alter the end time of my datetime field?

```
case when CAST([pcpts].stopit As DateTime)+CAST(case when CAST([pcpts].stopit As Time) > '11:00:00.000' then '11:00:00.000' ELSE CAST([pcpts].stopit As Time) end as datetime) As [SI]
```

**EDIT**
What I am after is if the time value for [pcpts].stopit is > 11:00:00.000 I want my query to show 11:00:00.000,

if the time value for [pcpts].stopit is < 11:00:00.000 then show [pcpts].stopit

Examples would be:
`[pcpts].stopit = '01/01/2014 10:00:00.000'` 
query output should show '01/01/2014 10:00:00.000'

`[pcpts].stopit = '01/01/2014 16:00:00.000'`
query output should show '01/01/2014 11:00:00.000'

Comment: And what if the time is 16:47:32.765? Still output should be 11 am sharp?

Comment: Correct!  Anything > 11 a.m. should be displayed as 11 a.m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing is you will need to stop performing shorthand math operations like + against date/time values. [This breaks when you switch to the newer types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations), which you should do.

For this particular problem, you can simply use a `CASE` expression to either (a) return the `datetime` as is, or (b) convert to `date` and then add 11 hours.

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, col) < 11 
  THEN col
  ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, col)))
END
```